# How can I hold data `None` in a Protobuf bytes field?

Tags: python, byte, nonetype

I'm developing a SDK of Python version. The data should be None in some cast, others should be bytes. But I don't know how to define a variable to hold the data?

I use `protoc` to generate python code, then create a transaction object, then update the data `script_sig`. In some case it should be `None`, but if I set it None, it occurs the error : `TypeError: None has type NoneType, but expected one of: bytes`

Here is my code:

```
message Transaction { 
  repeated TxIn vin = 2; 
  repeated TxOut vout = 3; 
} 

message TxIn { 
  OutPoint prev_out_point = 1; 
  bytes script_sig = 2; 
  uint32 sequence = 3; 
}
```

```
for i in range(len(tx.vin)):
  if i != index:
    tx.vin[index].script_sig = None
  else:
    tx.vin[index].script_sig = script_pub_key
```

How can I do about this? thx.

Comment: BTW,   sig is of bytes type.  If the data is None, it has the error:  `TypeError: None has type NoneType, but expected one of: bytes`

Comment: Python is dynamically typed language. So you can do something like this: `if condition: x = None; else x = b'aaaa'`. Probably you have to give more information about this error and provide a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thx for replying. My situaction is like this.  I created a  proto file like: ```message Transaction {
    int32 version = 1;
    repeated TxIn vin  = 2;
    repeated TxOut vout  = 3;
    Data data = 4;
    uint32 magic = 5;
    int64 lock_time = 6;
}

message TxIn {
    OutPoint prev_out_point = 1;
    bytes script_sig = 2;
    uint32 sequence = 3;
}```    then I generated python code use protoc command.    and I created a tx, I should update the script_sig data,  but it  had  the error if I  set it None.

Comment: I recommend editing the question and provide a nice format better readable for others.

Comment: okay, thx.  I did that.

Answer (score 1):

You can either store an empty `bytes` object (`b''`), or change the data type to `optional bytes`:

```
optional bytes script_sig = 2;
```

Comment: Thx.    ` _b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
           tx.vin[index].script_sig = _b('')`     I use this.  It has no type error, but the result is not right.

Comment: And the proto file is create by others, I can't change it.

Comment: No error occured.  But  the result isn't equal to the expected one

Comment: >>> import sys
>>> _b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
>>> b = _b('')  
>>> a = None
>>> print(b)

>>> print(a)
None
>>> print(a==b)
False .   None is not equals b''